# Proving that there is no invertible matrix with zero row sums using determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I have the following question which I know I should use the **determinant** to solve. Here it is:

> Determine if there exists an invertible $3\times3$ matrix $A$ such that
>   $$\begin{align*}
> a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{13}&=0 \\
> a_{21}+a_{22}+a_{23}&=0 \\
> a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{33}&=0
> \end{align*}$$

I know that the answer is no, that there is no such matrix, but I’d like to know how to solve this question with **determinants**.

Comment: You say you should use the determinant to solve this, but I would like to add that I think you should not do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant is invariant under adding single multiples of one column to another. So using this we can add Column $2$ to Column $1$. Then add Column $3$ to Column $1$. This results in a column of zeroes. Hence, the determinant of $A$ is $0$ so it cannot be invertible.

Comment: but I don't understand a a column of zeros results, we didn't subtract columns, so how did we receive zeros?

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but you seem to impose a condition on $A$ that says if you add the columns together the resulting vector is the zero vector.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot. Thank you!!

Comment: Not at all. You're welcome!!